# Why does the compiler fail with "Cannot resolve reference Action with such signature"?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have written some code in Play Framework with Scala and I am getting error. It worked fine but suddenly I got error.

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.Postpage.render())
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot resolve reference Action with such signature
Type mismatch expected(Request[Anycontent]=>resultactual:request[AnyContent]=>Any)
Type mismatch expected(BodyParser[Anycontent]=>resultactual:request[AnyContent]=>Any)
cannot resolve symbol Ok
```

Comment: The real problem here is that it cannot resolve symbol Ok not, are you sure you've imported  play.api.mvc._ ?

Comment: Is that the only error? Are there others? Is `Controller` mixed in? It might be better to show the whole file.

Comment: yes this is the only error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're explicitly calling `render` method in `Ok` object:

```
def index = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.Postpage.render())
}
```

Remove `.render()` and start over.

Ensure that `app/views/Postpage.scala.html` exists.